# Create an inline telegram bot without "bot" at the end of it's name

Tags: inline, bots, telegram

I want to create an inline telegram bot and have short name for it but botfather enforce me to locate "bot" at the end of it's name, I would be really grateful if anyone could help me in this issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to create `@___bot` to develop a awesome bot.

After you have many users, contact [@BotSupport](https://t.me/BotSupport) to ask to rename it.

But unfortunately, even [@combot](https://t.me/combot), who ever renamed from [@comstatbot](https://t.me/comstatbot), doesn't have human-like name :(

Comment: Yet somehow `@like`, `@bold` etc. do